# Java regex to extract text INSIDE tags

Tags: java, regex

I'm not very good with Regex (using *JAVA*) and i would like some help to get texts that are inside the tags <>
For example, the text:

```
Hello, my name is <NAME>, i'm <YEAR> years old, and i live in <ADRESS>
```

And i need an ArrayList or array[] of Strings with: **NAME, YEAR, ADRESS**

Comment: This is really straight forward using `"(?<=<)[^>]*"` regex.

Comment: regex to match the text within `<>` is `(?<=<)[^><]+(?=>)`

Comment: @anubhava - why positive look-behind?. A simple Pattern / Matcher could solve it right?

Comment: Why a downvote? Because it is simple to somebody i can't ask it?
Thank you for the answers, if you could provide as an answer i can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @TheLostMind same question , why a capturing group, simple lookbehind will do the job.

Comment: @BrunoFranco: I didn't downvote but usually questions without showing any effort are not encouraged here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - because I believe `\\w+` is more *readable*. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Pattern and Matcher with `<(\\w+)>` will work.
PS : you need to use `matcher.group(1)` to extract the actual text.

Check [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/zX2nF6/2)
So, something like this will work.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(\\w+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher();
while(m.find()){
// m.group(1) will give you values of name year and address(address is not returned completely if it is space delimited, you can use `<(.*?)>` to get entire address)
}
```

Comment: Btw, with this pattern it will return with the <>, i asked to just the content inside of it. (?<=<)[^><]+(?=>) did it

Comment: @BrunoFranco - you will have to use `m.group(1)` not `m.group()`

Comment: aww my falt, as i said, i'm regex newbie, thank you.